# How to constrain model variables in GEKKO

Tags: gekko

I like to constrain the variable value u < 1 in y model. Added ub=1 to the variable definition u = m.Var(name='u', value=0, lb=-2, ub=1) but it resulted in "No soulution found" (EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible.). I guess I have to reformulate the problem to avoid this, but I have not been able to find examples how this should be done. How do i write a proper model to avoid infeasible solutions when constraining variable values?

I hav tied to reformulate the problem by adding equation like m.Equation(u < 1) with no success.

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplt


m = GEKKO(remote=False)

t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 101)  # time 
d = np.ones(t.shape)
d[0:10] = 0
y_delay=0

# Add data to model
m.time = t
K = m.Const(0.01, name='K')
r = m.Const(name='r', value=0)  # Reference
d = m.Param(name='d', value=d)  # Disturbance
y = m.Var(name='y', value=0, lb=-2, ub=2)  # State variable
u = m.Var(name='u', value=0, lb=-2, ub=1)  # Output
e = m.Var(name='e', value=0)
Tc = m.FV(name='Tc', value=1200, lb=60, ub=1200)  # time constant

# Update variable status
Tc.STATUS = 1  # Optimizer can adjust value

Kp = m.Intermediate(1 / K * 1 / Tc, name='Kp')
Ti = m.Intermediate(4 * Tc, name='Ti')

# Model equations
m.Equations([y.dt() == K * (u-d),
             e == r-y,
             u.dt() == Kp*e.dt()+Kp/Ti*e])

# Model constraints
m.Equation(y < 0.5)
m.Equation(y > -0.5)

# Model objective
m.Obj(-Tc)

# options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # Problem type: 6 = Dynamic optimization

# solve
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
print('Tc: %6.2f [s]' % (Tc.value[-1], ))

fig1, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = pyplt.subplots(3, sharex='all')
ax1.plot(t, y.value)
ax1.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=8), ax1.grid(True, which='both')
ax2.plot(t, e.value)
ax2.set_ylabel("e", fontsize=8), ax2.grid(True, which='both')
ax3.plot(t, u.value)
ax3.plot(t, d.value)
ax3.set_ylabel("u and d", fontsize=8), ax3.grid(True, which='both')
pyplt.show()
```

EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible.

An error occured.
 The error code is  2

If I change the upper bound of u to 2, the optimization problem is solved as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Hard constraints on variables can lead to an infeasible solution, as you observed. I recommend that you use soft constraints by specifying the variable `y` as a Controlled Variable and set an upper and lower set point range with `SPHI` and `SPLO`.

```py
y = m.CV(name='y', value=0)  # Controlled variable
y.STATUS = 1
y.TR_INIT = 0
y.SPHI = 0.5
y.SPLO = -0.5
```

I also removed the `lb` and `ub` from `y` and `u` to not give them hard bounds that can lead to the infeasibility. You also have an objective to maximize the value of `Tc` with `m.Obj(-Tc)`. It goes to the maximum limit: `1200` when the solver is able to adjust the value. As you can see from the plot, the value of `y` exceeds the setpoint range. It may not be possible for the controller to keep it within that range. A soft constraint (objective based) approach to constraints penalizes deviations but does not lead to an infeasible solution. If you need to increase the penalty on violations of the `SPHI` or `SPLO`, the parameters `WSPHI` and `WSPLO` can be adjusted.

[image: test results]

It appears that you have a first order dynamic model and you are trying to optimize PID parameters. If you need to model saturation of the controller output (actuator) then the `if3`, `max3`, `min3` or corresponding `if2`, `max2`, `min2` functions may be useful. There is more information on `CV` [objectives](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective) and [tuning](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerTuning) in the Dynamic Optimization course.

[image: CV Tuning Demonstration]

Here is a feasible solution to your problem:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplt

m = GEKKO() # remote=False

t = np.linspace(0, 1000, 101)  # time 
d = np.ones(t.shape)
d[0:10] = 0
y_delay=0

# Add data to model
m.time = t
K = m.Const(0.01, name='K')
r = m.Const(name='r', value=0)  # Reference
d = m.Param(name='d', value=d)  # Disturbance
e = m.Var(name='e', value=0)
u = m.Var(name='u', value=0)  # Output
Tc = m.FV(name='Tc', value=1200, lb=60, ub=1200)  # time constant

y = m.CV(name='y', value=0)  # Controlled variable
y.STATUS = 1
y.TR_INIT = 0
y.SPHI = 0.5
y.SPLO = -0.5

# Update variable status
Tc.STATUS = 1  # Optimizer can adjust value

Kp = m.Intermediate((1 / K) * (1 / Tc), name='Kp')
Ti = m.Intermediate(4 * Tc, name='Ti')

# Model equations
m.Equations([y.dt() == K * (u-d),
             e == r-y,
             u.dt() == Kp*e.dt()+(Kp/Ti)*e])

# Model constraints
#m.Equation(y < 0.5)
#m.Equation(y > -0.5)

# Model objective
m.Obj(-Tc)

# options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # Problem type: 6 = Dynamic optimization
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

# solve
m.solve(disp=True, debug=True)
print('Tc: %6.2f [s]' % (Tc.value[-1], ))

fig1, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = pyplt.subplots(3, sharex='all')
ax1.plot(t, y.value)
ax1.plot([min(t),max(t)],[0.5,0.5],'k--')
ax1.plot([min(t),max(t)],[-0.5,-0.5],'k--')
ax1.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=8), ax1.grid(True, which='both')
ax2.plot(t, e.value)
ax2.set_ylabel("e", fontsize=8), ax2.grid(True, which='both')
ax3.plot(t, u.value)
ax3.plot(t, d.value)
ax3.set_ylabel("u and d", fontsize=8), ax3.grid(True, which='both')
pyplt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for an extensive and useful answer to my question. I really appreciate it.
As you correctly observed I am trying to optimize tuning parameters for my simple control problem. I have executed your code with soft constraints, and it sure solves the feasibility issue. I also added the WSPHI/LO parameters and set their values high to have a solution within the constraints. Still, I like to have a model where the control output (“u”) is bounded [0,1]. Based on your answer I probably must add “if” or “max/min” statements in the model to avoid having a non-feasible set of equations when “u” hits the bound. Something like “if u<0, u.dt() = 0 else u.dt() = Kp*e ….”. Could it alternatively be possible to add a variable (a type slack variable) to ensure feasibility of the equation set? I will also investigate the material in the dynamic optimization course links to get a better understanding of dynamic modelling. Thanks again for guiding me in the right direction in this issue.

Comment: Yes, a slack variable could also work. Here is more info on slack variables: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/SlackVariables  In the future, I recommend that you add a comment to the response instead of creating a new answer to your original question.

Comment: this should be a comment to an answer instead of another answer